# Example about a function differentiable at 0

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a function $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$, such that the value of the derivative at $0$ is $0$, but $0$ is neither a local maximum or local minimum.

I choose $f(x)=x^2$ when $x\ge 0$ and $f(x)=-x^2$ when $x<0$?
I see the function is continuous at $0$. But I am not sure if it is differentiable at $0$ or not?

So could anyone help me with this?

Comment: $f(x)=x^3{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Try $$f(x)=x^3$$ ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

$f'(0)=0$ , but it's neither a local minima nor local maxima. It's an [inflection point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point?wprov=sfla1).

Comment: Got it thank you sooooooo much

Comment: I got it, but what do u think about my function

Comment: @Ahmed Your function also works correctly. It's differentiable at $x=0$. (Both RHD=LHD=0) and $0$ is an inflection point in this case too.

Comment: Inf**l**ection point!